# Rust: как пересобрать строку и добавить экранирование к каждому символу строки?

Tags: rust

Как лучше добавить к каждому символу в строке экранирование "\" ? Пройти строку в цикле, получим посимвольное ее, а как добавить к каждому символу "\" и снова собрать все в строку?

Answer (score 1):

А где-то поискать самому? Первое, что попалось: [Создание функции на Rust, которая возвращает String или &str](https://habr.com/ru/articles/274565/).

Берём оттуда кусок кода и переделываем:

```
fn total_escaping(input: &str) -> String {
   let mut buf = String::with_capacity(2 * input.len());
   for c in input.chars() {
       buf.push('\');
       buf.push(c);
   }
}
```

Но я очень подозреваю, что должна быть стандартная функция, которая экранирует все нуждающиеся в этом символы.

Вот, что-то нашёл [Function escape_string::escape](https://docs.rs/escape_string/latest/escape_string/fn.escape.html)

Comment: Моя первая программа на RUST!

Comment: За найденное решение спасибо. Поискать мог сам да. Вопрос был в экранировании каждого символа в строке, а не в стандартных функциях , которые экранируют "все нуждающиеся символы".

Comment: Спасибо в карман не положишь.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал все через цикл и посимвольное чтение. Да и как-то проще все должно быть.

```
let mut string = String::new();
    for i in hostname.chars() {
        string.push('\\');
        string.push(i);
        
    }

    print!("{}", string);
```

Comment: Проще в данном случае не значит быстрее. Не знаю, как там RUST работает, но выделение буфера известного размера под строку "String::with_capacity" сделано не зря, видимо.

Comment: Это делается для того, чтобы избежать дополнительных динамических перераспределений для увеличения внутреннего хранилища кучи, используемого строкой. Если  известен размер строки , можно через with_capacity получить одно выделение заранее. У меня размер не известен, он разный. Не уверен, что with_capacity будет быстрее.

Comment: Как это неизвестен? Он в два раза больше, чем входная строка "2 * input.len()".